# Load opencart without the template (or use some parts of it outside the template)

Tags: php, e-commerce, opencart

I'm working on a website I didn't make in the first place. It's made in 2 parts: the presentation website, and the OpenCart for the e-commerce part.

I need to use some functions of OpenCart, especially to have an access to the main tools (cart, price of the items in the cart ...) in the presentation website (not in the OpenCart template).

So I was wondering if there is any way I can load OpenCart and it's functions, without loading the template when I don't need it.

I know it may sound counter intuitive and may rise the page load time, but I don't have much choice, given the time I have to do this and the experience I lack with OpenCart.

EDIT:
Okay so I added this at the bottom of the index.php file of open cart:

```
if($_GET['module'] == 'website') { 
    include('website/index.php'); 
} else { 
    // Output 
    $response->output(); 
}
```

So in theory, OpenCart is loaded onto my website. But my guess in that output() calls the template AND it's controller, so I don't have access to the variables I need: $login, $text_login, $cart, $checkout ... the toolbox variables. I guess I need to call the controller, but I have no idea what controller is used for what variable... if you have an idea, I would be really thankful.

Thanks, Antoine

Comment: All products added to cart reside in a `$_SESSION`. If You are able to access the same session for OpenCart in Your presentation, then it is the easiest way to just work with the session data for the cart directly in Your presentation. I don't know what framework/tool do You use for Your presentation but it may happen that after mixing classes from both of them You may end up with some collisions or as You said - rising the page load time (**do not underestimate this one!**). If You need some special logic, then it is better to *port it over* from OC to Your presentation framework/tool...

Answer (score 2):

This will require quite a bit of work. You will essentially need to duplicate the index.php file in the catalog side and not run the final piece of the code, namely this

```
// Maintenance Mode
$controller->addPreAction(new Action('common/maintenance'));

// Router
if (isset($request->get['route'])) {
    $action = new Action($request->get['route']);
} else {
    $action = new Action('common/home');
}

// Dispatch
$controller->dispatch($action, new Action('error/not_found'));
```

and then you can set up your own actions to show code etc or load the necessary classes directly

Comment: Okay so I added this at the bottom of the index.php file of open cart:

if($_GET['module'] == 'website') {
 include('website/index.php');
} else {
 // Output
 $response->output();
}

So in theory, OpenCart is loaded onto my website. But my guess in that output() calls the template AND it's controller, so I don't have access to the variables I need: $login, $text_login, $cart, $checkout ... the toolbox variables. I guess I need to call the controller, but I have no idea what controller is used for what variable... if you have an idea, I would be thankful.

Thanks a lot